# Contacting new company's employees before joining the job

Tags: job-change, human-resources

I got an offer from a company after a series of interviews and I accepted it. I browsed some of the company's employee profiles in LinkedIn and connected with them since they interviewed me.

Is it ok to connect with the people on LinkedIn who have interviewed you irrespective of the fact you where offered a job or not?

Since the company might have no information on Glassdoor for the appropriate region to lookup the experiences. Is it ok to discuss with their employees about the company culture, work timings etc. or is HR the only point of contact before joining the job ?

I am new to changing jobs as its my first job change. I cited LinkedIn as an option and I am open to other means to know about the company in general.

Comment: seems a bit weird to me, but we're not big on social media here

Comment: @Kilisi I just wanted to understand about the culture and I cited social media and Glassdoor as a possible option. I am open to any other means to know about the company before I join. May be I can add it to the question

Comment: You said "social media" but I think you may get different answers if you mean LinkedIn or Facebook; if someone I interviewed contacted me on LinkedIn I'd be more receptive than if they'd found me on Facebook.

Comment: @RJFalconer Thanks. I meant LinkedIn and have edited the question to LinkedIn to be more specific.

Comment: In my working days I barely wanted to know a new employee beyond whatever is necessary for the work. In some jobs I didn't even bother learning someones name until they'd been around a few months... so if a new employee added me on a social network I wouldn't be happy about it... however I don't do Linkdin....

Comment: It sounds like you have more questions that you forgot to ask during the interviews. Don't be shy. Why don't you email HR and ask them to set up a phone call between one of those people and yourself because you have more questions that you forgot to ask? That would be better I think.

Answer (score 1):

If the culture is a bad fit it would be better for both you and the company if you declined the job offer rather than quit after a short time. By that logic it seems reasonable to talk to developers via LinkedIn.

Answer (score 0):

I don't connect with lots of people I've worked with for years. LinkedIn is about networking, and I don't see any benefit of having a LI connection with someone I can just ping on the chat system at work.

If a new employee wanted to contact me on LI, I'd probably answer that I didn't know that person.